# Stack xarray DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have N 1D `xr.DataArray`'s with an 1 `array` coordinate `b` and 1 `scalar` coordinate `a`. I want to combine them to a 2D `DataArray` with `array` coordinates `b`, `a`. How to do this? I have tried:

```py
x1 = xr.DataArray(np.arange(0,3)[...,np.newaxis], coords=[('b', np.arange(3,6)),('a', [10])]).squeeze()
x2 = xr.DataArray(np.arange(0,3)[...,np.newaxis], coords=[('b', np.arange(3,6)),('a', [11])]).squeeze()

xcombined = xr.concat([x1, x2])
xcombined
```

Results in :

```py
<xarray.DataArray (concat_dims: 2, b: 3)>
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) int64 3 4 5
    a        (concat_dims) int64 10 11
Dimensions without coordinates: concat_dims
```

Now I like to select a particularly 'a':

```
xcombined.sel(a=10)
```

However, this raises:

```
ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['a'] do not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply `dim` to `concat`, this works:

```
xcombined = xr.concat([x1, x2], dim='a')
```

And then:

```
xcombined.sel(a=10)

<xarray.DataArray (b: 3)>
array([0, 1, 2])
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) int64 3 4 5
    a        int64 10
```

Comment: But now the information in array x2 (specifining values for a=11) are missing

Comment: Right, because `x2` doesn't have `a=10`. If you look at `xcombined` without calling `.sel(a=10)`, you'll also see values for `a=11`